# Getting Code.gs function value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I would like to put a function created in Code.gs in JavaScript as a condition. Not sure if it's possible, because I tried different approaches and JavaScript still can't regognize the value.

This is what I have:

**Code.gs**

```js
function CheckifAdmin() {
    var admins = ['email@domain.com'];
    for (var i = 0; i < admins.length; i++) {
        if (admins[i] == Session.getActiveUser()) {
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

**JavaScript**

```js
function ChangeEmail() {
    google.script.run.CheckifAdmin();
    if (CheckifAdmin() == true) {
        var newemail = prompt("Please enter new email");
        document.getElementById('form_email').value = newemail;
    } else {
        alert("You do not have needed permissions.")
    }
}
```

Maybe you could advice how to handle it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gs:

```
function CheckifAdmin() {
  const admins = ['email@domain.com'];
  return ~admins.indexOf(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());
}
```

Javascript:

```
function ChangeEmail() {
    google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler((v) => {
      if(v) {
        //code if true
      } else {
        //code if false
      }
    })
    .CheckifAdmin();
}
```